# How to Merge rows in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried digging this stuff and have no solution so I'm hoping someone can assist. I have a sheet with the following:

Data

```
123|456|789        
111|222|333
```

etc...

Result Needed

```
|123 456 789|        
|111 222 333|
```

etc...

I'm trying to avoid formulas (`=Concat`) and (`=A2&" "&B2&" "&C2`) etc...

I tried `sheet.getRange(2,1,1,2).mergeAcross()`; and it merged the cells and kept he left-most value. Google searches point to the formula solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Array.join()` for each row:

#### Snippet:

```
var jointRowsArray = sheet
  .getRange(2, 1, 2, 3) //A2:C4
  .getValues()
  .map(function(row) { 
    return [row.join(' ')];//join Each row
  });
sheet.getRange(2, 4, jointRowsArray.length, 1).setValues(jointRowsArray);
```

#### To Read:

- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Range#setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Thanks TheMaster my Logger is showing that the data merged however when the last line executes I'm receiving an error "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]" This looks positive, when I change the range to 2,1,1,3 and change setValues to setValue it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var range  = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,2)  
var values = range.getValues()

range.clearContent()

sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(values.join(' '));
```

You can pull the values into JS and then join and insert them into a single cell.  You can also place this inside an iterator and do something akin to `getRange(i,1,1,2)`.  This can be triggered manually or by an edit hook.

However, this seems like the perfect fit for a single formula.

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C),,COLUMNS(A:C)))`

The formula would go on the first row in perhaps column D. `JOIN` functions cannot usually be arrayed in google sheets, and you would normally have to put a formula in for every row.  However, here we are tricking the sheet into thinking our data is the header and displaying it accordingly.

Comment: Hi Tom, i appreciate your response. The reason why I'm avoiding formulas because when I choose to write the information on a new column or sheet I get errors because it's including the formula cells so its throwing off the row length. so when I log the data it shows [123, 456, 789], [],[],[],[] <-- blanks represent my formulas. I tried the formula and I have an error of: "Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (1)." Js code snippet shows error : TypeError: Cannot find function flat in object 123,456,789. (file Code.gs, line 41)

Comment: To avoid that error the formula must be on the top row of the data. If you are doing a full column `A:C` it needs to be on row 1.  `A2:C` can go on row 2 and so on.

Comment: re: TypeError I removed the call to `flat()`.  It was causing the error and is not needed.  Sorry about that.